# How to pass the value from parent component to child component on load in LWC?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have this scenario. I am having a getRecord wire method in parent component which is assigning a field value to the variable. That value is passed to the child component. I have a connectedCallback() function in the child component which is having some logic based on the value passed through the parent component.

Issue: The wire method in parent component is running after the connected callback() function in the child component and getting the value as undefined even though the record has value on that field. Can anyone help in resolving this.

**Parent Component:**
JS

```
import STATUS_FIELD from @salesforce/schema/customObject__c.status__c;
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

const FIELDS = [STATUS_FIELD];

@api recId
@track status;
@track error;

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recId', fields: FIELDS}) details({error,data}) {
if(data) {
this.status = data.fields.status__c.value;
} else {
this.error = error;
}
}
```

HTML (calling child component)

```
<template >
<child-component status-value={status} >
</child-component>
</template>
```

**CHILD Component**

JS

```
@api statusValue;

connectedCallback() {

if(this.statusValue == 'Finished'){
//some logic
}
}
//statusValue is coming as undefined here but the value is actually Finished.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes in parent component and it will start working.

**Parent Component:** JS

```
import STATUS_FIELD from @salesforce/schema/customObject__c.status__c;
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

const FIELDS = [STATUS_FIELD];

@api recId
@track status;
@track error;
@track flagIndicatingDataHasBeenLoadedInVariables = false;

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recId', fields: FIELDS}) details({error,data}) {
if(data) {
this.status = data.fields.status__c.value;
this.flagIndicatingDataHasBeenLoadedInVariables = true;
} else {
this.error = error;
}
}
```

HTML (calling child component)

```
<template if:true={flagIndicatingDataHasBeenLoadedInVariables}>
     <child-component status-value={status} >
     </child-component>
</template>
```

**Explanation**: We are setting a flag after the data is loaded. Only after data is loaded in the parent, it will be passed to the child component.

Answer (score 4):

Here parent component is passing *account-name* prop to child. You don't need connectedCallback() in child for the custom logic, rather you need **renderedCallback()**.
[More detailed documentation here](https://lwc.dev/guide/lifecycle)

child.html

```
<template>
    <p>Helllo this is child</p>
    <p>{accountName}</p>    
</template>
```

child.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api accountName;
    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('Hello this is in render');
        console.log(this.accountName);
        **add you conditional business logic here**
    }
}
```

parent.html

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="My Account Record" icon-name="standard:account">
    <template if:true={account.data}>
        <c-child-component account-name={name}>
        </c-child-component>
    </template>
    <template if:true={account.error}>
        {account.error}
    </template>
</lightning-card>
```

parent.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';

export default class TestSO extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD] })
    account;

    get name() {
        return this.account.data.fields.Name.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: When including logic in the renderedCallback function, you should create a variable to store when it runs, otherwise it will execute every time the component re-renders. A simple `if (this.initialized)` and `this.initialized=true` will do.